# A few questions about adding gitignore after multiple commits

Tags: git, github

I have created my `gitignore` file and have added it to my local repo. I understand that I have to do `git rm --cached`. So here are my questions.

- When in the process should I do `git rm --cached`? before `git add --all .` or `git commit -m "comments"` or `git push origin master`? Also before or after committing (or pushing) my `gitignore`?
- Is `git rm --cached` the whole command? or must I always qualify it with, for example, `git rm --cached /bin/*`?
- my mac computer gave me a warning about naming my file `.gitignore` vs `android.gitignore`. If I simply do `.gitignore` the file will be hidden. Does github care which one I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. git rm --cached filename is used to stop tracking a file without deleting it from your working tree. Example:
   You create a new file, start tracking with git add, and then commit.
   You want to ignore the file, so you add it to .gitignore
   git is still tracking the file when you make changes to it, this is when you git rm --cached
   git thinks the file is gone, but it's still there in your local directory.
2. git rm --cached filename for whichever file you want to ignore.
3. yes, it needs to be .gitignore

Comment: Many thanks. So can I untracked a whole folder at once, as in `/bin/*`? Also is that the correct syntax? I have seen `/\*.exe`. Does that mean it should be `/\bin/\*`

Comment: Yes, and that's correct syntax. I think in the case of \*.exe, the backslash was used to escape the *, so it would target a file that was literally named *.exe, rather than any file with .exe extension.
edit: Many thanks for first upvote! Also, if this answer helped you, would you mind marking it as the accepted answer? :)

Comment: One last thing: should I really be using `git rm -r --cached /bin/*` or is using `-r` a bad idea here? I get a complaint about not removing recursively because I am not using `-r`. I don't mean this for `/bin/*` specifically, but generally speaking.

Comment: actually I find the correct syntax. The `-r` must come after `--cached`

Comment: Well that depends what's in /bin/*. If there are files in there that aren't targeted by .gitignore, then git status will show them as untracked files, after you rm --cached recursively. It all depends what you're trying to achieve, but .gitignore should target the same files that rm --cached targets and only these files. It doesn't have any bad consequences to do otherwise but it also doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

You should use git rm --cached before "git add" and you should list the files in .gitignore.  The relationship of git rm to committing/pushing .gitignore is not relevant, but please do perform "git add" after you change .gitignore locally.

Github recognizes .gitignore and that is what you should use.